# Can common prepositions following a verb be dropped freely?

Tags: idioms, prepositions

Specifically, within the sentence *"to sing along to/with"*, can to/with be dropped freely?

While searching for information I found out [this seems to be an idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sing+along), so possibly my question should be extended to: *"Can common prepositions following a verb be dropped freely when used within an idiom?"*

The full sentence which inspired this question was: *"But I'll write a song for one day we'll sing along"*. The intended meaning behind this is the following: *"I will write the song, and here's why: one day we'll sing it together"*. The original phrasing sounded incorrect to me both in regards to the usage of 'for', as well as it sounding weird since 'with' or 'to' is missing.

The question is whether or not this is grammatically correct. Can the phrasing 'sing along' be used without 'with' or 'to' following it?

Comment: The correct sentence should be "I'll write a song for the day on which we sing along."

Comment: Also, it's perfectly fine to end the expression without "with / to."  "OK, everybody, sing along!"  "I like it when you sing along."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "But I'll write a song for one day we'll sing along"

This is a perfectly grammatical sentence, if the intended meaning of "for" is "because". This would be especially appropriate since the sentence sounds poetic, and the use of "for" in this meaning is considered literary or old-fashioned.

> *for*: conj.
>   Because; since.

([American Heritage Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/for))

In the sentence you provided, the trailing "to" is dropped because in that clause ("for one day we'll sing along") there is no explicitly stated object of singing along to.

EDIT: If the conjunction "for" is indeed used to mean "because" (sounds like it), I'd put a comma in there:

> I'll write a song, for one day we'll sing along.

Comment: You nailed the point why for is not a conjunction.

Comment: I think it *is* a conjunction, otherwise the sentence sounds very awkward (or is ungrammatical) and the OP rightly rewrote it to "I'll write a song for **the day** we'll sing along". Regarding the comma: Are you saying it's mandatory? Would you put a comma in "I like singing and dancing for/because they are lots of fun"?

Comment: @for I would not use the word "mandatory" but "most of the time" and it is rarely used nowadays. Any reason you have to think for is a conjunction? It makes perfect sense as a preposition. No?

Comment: I interpret the sentence to mean "I will write the song, and here's why: one day we'll sing along". The writer is giving their reason for writing the song. You can replace "for" with "because", so "for" is a conjunction connecting two clauses. I didn't look into the comma issue very deeply, but I think it would add clarity. I'm not sure it's mandatory to use a comma here, even though "for" is a conjunction. As a preposition, "for" makes no sense to me (the way the sentence is worded). It should be "for the day" or possibly "for the one day".

Comment: If you look at most of the usages in a dictionary, commas are there. There is a reason to use a comma and you explained well in the answer. Is my interpretation particularly wrong?

Comment: The day (for which the song was written) they will sing along  has not come yet and it is unknown when it will be. If the day is fixed like the Independence Day, it might be. But you don't usually use one day or the day for such a specific day. You use "one day" for unknown future unspecific day. It is like comma before "for" as a conjunction. One day or the day both could be used.

Comment: The exact date of singing along is not known, correct, by it's not just *any* day. It is the *day we'll sing along*. It's being thought of as a specific day. Hence, the definite article, is, I think, required (didn't check any grammar books now, can't give a reference.) I would not use "I am thinking about **a day** we will get married". It doesn't sound right for the exact same reason.

Comment: We might have had to ask the context, first. I will stop here. You are right about the "a day" part.

Comment: I have deleted my answer as the context is not clear. :)

Comment: _"In the sentence you provided, the trailing "to" is dropped because in that clause ("for one day we'll sing along") there is no explicitly stated object of singing along to."_ You correctly interpret the meaning is that it is _"I will write the song, and here's why: one day we'll sing [the song] along"_. The object of singing along to is hence implicitly 'the song'. I take it from you answer this still means it is correct.

Comment: @Rathony Included context into the original question.

Comment: @StevenJeuris My decision was the right one and A.P's answer is correct. Please remember to put comma before "for"  as A.P. advised. Context is the most important thing when asking questions. Good luck! -:)

Comment: @StevenJeuris Yes, "But I'll write a song for one day we'll sing along" is correct.